Finding the coordinates of a point in 3D space
I'm looking for a point in 3D space using three spheres
To find a point, I use a system of three equations of spheres (I know the coordinates of the points of the spheres and their radii)
If the desired point is located in z at a height higher than or equal to the center of the point, then the desired point is searched normally
But if it’s lower, then the z coordinate is being searched incorrectly
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def GetTag3DCoordinates(anchors, radii):

    # Сортировка радиусов и сфер по id
    anchors = sorted(anchors, key=lambda x: x[0])
    radii = sorted(radii, key=lambda x: x[0])

    # Извлечение второго значения радиуса для расчетов 
    radii = [r[1] for r in radii]

    def residuals(vars, anchors, radii):
        x, y, z = vars
        debug = [np.sqrt((x - ax)**2 + (y - ay)**2 + (z - az)**2) - r 
                 for (_, ax, ay, az), r in zip(anchors, radii)]
        return debug
    
    # Сортировка радиусов и выбор трех минимальных
    sorted_radii = np.argsort(radii)
    selected_indices = sorted_radii[:3]

    selected_anchors = [anchors[i] for i in selected_indices]
    selected_radii = [radii[i] for i in selected_indices]
    
    # Начальное приближение для координат метки (центр якорей)
    x0 = np.mean([a[1] for a in selected_anchors])
    y0 = np.mean([a[2] for a in selected_anchors])
    z0 = np.mean([a[3] for a in selected_anchors])

    initial_guess = [x0, y0, z0]

    try:
        # Оптимизация методом наименьших квадратов с использованием всех якорей
        result1 = least_squares(residuals, initial_guess, args=(selected_anchors, selected_radii))

        final_result1 = np.array([result1.x[0], result1.x[1], result1.x[2]])

        # Возвращаем оба результата
        return final_result1
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        return np.array([-1, -1, -1]), np.array([-1, -1, -1])
    
# Пример использования функции
if __name__ == "__main__":
    anchors = [
        (1, 222.8, 125.4, 69.4),
        (2, 222.8, 191.2, 69.4),
        (3, 347.9, 125.6, 69.4),
        (4, 347.9, 191.2, 69.4)
    ]

    radii = [
        (1, 164.4),
        (2, 109.6),
        (3, 221.4),
        (4, 184.4)
    ]

    tag_coords1 = GetTag3DCoordinates(anchors, radii)
    print("Координаты метки 1: x={:.2f}, y={:.2f}, z={:.2f}".format(*tag_coords1))


I don’t know exactly where the error is, but I have an assumption that the error may be in the least squares method

Please could you explain your problem more clearly. Are you saying that you know the distance to three points and you want to know where you are (in which case it would be irrelevant that those points were the centres of spheres) ... or do you want a point whose sum of distances from three points is minimal .... or is it something else? Please provide a better explanation, a diagram and, ideally, a minimum working example.

I believe there may be a problem with the initial guess. This method may struggle to find the correct solution if the initial guess is too far away. Try to do it with a weighted average based on the radii of the spheres. (I hope it helps Im not sure if this ok but its my first guess)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

When you generate your initial guess your example code shows
x0 = np.mean([a[1] for a in selected_anchors])
y0 = np.mean([a[2] for a in selected_anchors])
z0 = np.mean([a[3] for a in selected_anchors])

However python is zero indexed, so I would expect this to start with a[0], a[1], a[2].
a[3], (if it exists) is an unused number. This will lead to a broken z0 and a bad initial guess if z is involved.
